# VBA - copy paste macro help needed

Tags: excel, vba

Need help with a macro that will open 5 different csv files and automatically auto copy paste 3 columns of data (starting from the 2nd row to about the 200th row). Then the data will be pasted into one worksheet that is open so each file is all on one row (side by side)...any help will be appreciated..

```
Sub Macro2() 
    'Assign variable name to Target workbook 
    Var1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name 
    'Assign variable name to Target range 
    Var1R = "H1" 
    'Open Source WorkBook 
    Application.Workbooks.Open ("C:\MY DOCUMENTS\WORKBOOK(B).xls") 
    'Assign variable name to Source workbook 
    Var2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name 
    Var2R = "WORKSHEET-1" 
    'Copy from Source to Target 
    Sheets(Var2R).Columns("F").EntireColumn.Copy _     
    Destination:=Workbooks(Var1).Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Var1R) 
    'Close Source WorkBook wo/Save 
    Workbooks(Var2).Close False 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a program that will do that.  Obviously you'll have to modify the file-paths and ranges.

```
Sub copy_paste()
Dim filepaths
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim x As Long

Set twb = ThisWorkbook
filepaths = Array("C:\A.csv", "C:\B.csv", "C:\C.csv", "C:\D.csv", "C:\E.csv")

For x = 1 To UBound(filepaths)+1
    With Workbooks.Open(filepaths(x-1))
        .Sheets(1).Range("A2:C200").Copy twb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3 * x - 2)
        .Close False
    End With
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: it highlights this `.Sheets(OANDA_historical_position_ratio).Cells.Range("A2:C200").Copy twb.Sheets(OANDA_historical_position_ratio).Cells(2, 3 * x - 2)`

Comment: Your sheet name is not in quotes.  If you refer to a sheet by name, you need to use quotes.

Comment: ok i fixed that but get the same error. Should i be inputting the same sheet name in both places, maybe thats the reason for the error?    .Sheets ("OANDA_jistorical.......).Range().Copy twb Sheets (OANDA....

Comment: .Sheets("OANDA_historical_position_ratio").Range("A2:C200").Copy twb.Sheets("OANDA_historical_position_ratio").Cells(2, 3 * x - 2)  -  This code says "Copy A2:C200 from the "OANDA_historical_position_ratio" sheet of the workbook in this With block, and paste into row 2, column 3x-2 of the "OANDA_historical_position_ratio" sheet of the twb workbook.

Comment: No,  i want sheet (OANDA_hist...) to paste into the current worksheet (sheet 1) in the current open workbook..

Comment: Then you need to put `.Sheets("OANDA_historical_position_ratio").Range("A2:C200").Copy twb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 3 * x - 2)`  A tip for future posts: Include the exact names of the workbooks/sheets so that whoever answers can use them.

Comment: OK, now getting a new error     run time error 2147422    automation error

Comment: My code says "For each filepath given, open the workbook, copy from sheet1 into sheet1 of this workbook, then close it without changes."  It should do what you're asking.  I'm not sure why you're getting a run-time error.

Comment: I want my code to say "For each filepath given, open the workbook, copy from OANDA_historical sheet into sheet1 of this workbook (so that all the data from all 5 files is on one sheet) , then close it without changes."