# Issue with compile syntax error with macro

Tags: vba

I am trying to use this macro using 5 read only `.csv` files but get a compile error.

What am I doing wrong?

[VBA - copy paste macro help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809170/vba-copy-paste-macro-help-needed/30809674?noredirect=1#comment49732500_30809674)

Comment: And what is our compiler error? Then maybe we can help you.

Comment: Could you also Include the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

I compiled your code and it gave an error about a variable not declared on the following line:

```
.Sheets(1).Cells.Range("A2:C200").Copy wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3 * x - 2)
```

It should read:

```
.Sheets(1).Cells.Range("A2:C200").Copy twb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3 * x - 2)
```

Comment: i attached the link of my original question in the comment at the top

Comment: im trying to copy paste 3 columnns with 170 rows of the first sheet of 5 different read only csv files. the first file will copy paste cells a2 to c170 into sheet 1 of the current file. the 4 other files will copy paste b2 to c170 into the same sheet but each into adjacent columns.   so file 2 will pase its 2 columns of 170 rows in cell d2, file 3 into f2, file 4 into h2, file 5 into j2

Comment: Yes, I found your code. The answer above fixes the compile error.And what is your question wih your second comment? Please amend your original question or post a new one.